# How does the EU determine that invoking Article 7 against an EU member state is too harsh?

Tags: european-union

> In early 2000, Austria formed a government which included the
> right-wing populist[3][4] Freedom Party. Invoking Article 7 was deemed
> excessive so other member states threatened to cut off diplomatic
> contacts instead. This event led to a desire for an intermediate step
> to provide a warning sign without full suspension.[5][6]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_7_of_the_Treaty_on_European_Union#cite_note-pol11012016-6

The article mentions it was deemed too harsh, but how does the EU generally determine that invoking it would be too harsh. Is there some kind of voting, debate, or commissions with some representatives or officials? What's the full process of determining whether invoking the article is just or not.

Comment: Isn't this covered by the treaty text? It seems paragraph one and two of Article 7 cover exactly what is needed (i.e. who gets a vote and what margins are needed to proceed) for the suspension to be enacted. If it's not clear from that, can you clarify? Or are you asking about the specific Austrian example rather than the procedure more generally?

Comment: Exactly - the voting procedure is detailed and is fairly stringent.  Few people are fond of hard right wing parties, but suspending a country, essentially "just in case", just because they dared to form a government based on a coalition including such a party seems over the top and seems to deny agency to its voters.  And if the extreme right gets that treatment, should doctrinal Marxist Leninists coalition members not warrant it as well - where is that line drawn?  Why not wait till something along the line of article 7 concerns actually happens?